# Create Continuous Enrollment islands for a certain sub-population

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

My end goal is to create islands of continuous enrollment days for each `CLIENTID` for a single sub-population: 'Adult Expansion' for calendar years 2019 and 2020. A `CLIENTID` can be associated with multiple sub-populations in a calendar year, but can never be associated with more than one sub-population at once (there is no overlap in enrollment). My data go back to 2016, but I am only interested in 2019 and 2020. The data are structured that each row is a single enrollment period, with start and end dates of enrollment, associated with a sub-population.

I've included below some dummy data and a desired output to better illustrate my goal:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
CLIENTID NVARCHAR(9),
DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION NVARCHAR(30),
ELIGBEGIN DATE,
ELIGEND DATE, 
AGE INT
)
INSERT INTO #t
VALUES 
('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2019-12-16', '2019-12-31', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-15', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-31', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-30', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-31', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-30', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-31', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-08-01', '2020-08-31', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-30', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-31', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-11-01', '2020-11-30', 52)
, ('123456789', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-12-01', '2020-12-31', 52)
------------------------NEW CLIENTID-----------------------------
,('012345678', 'Demonstration Population #3', '2019-10-01', '2019-10-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Demonstration Population #3', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-30', 52)
,('012345678', 'Demonstration Population #3', '2019-12-01', '2019-12-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Demonstration Population #3', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-02-01', '2020-02-28', 52)
,('012345678', 'Demonstration Population #3', '2020-02-29', '2020-02-29', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-03-01', '2020-03-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-30', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-30', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-07-01', '2020-07-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-08-01', '2020-08-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-09-01', '2020-09-30', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-31', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-11-01', '2020-11-30', 52)
,('012345678', 'Adult Expansion', '2020-12-01', '2020-12-31', 52)
---------------------------NEW CLIENTID---------------------------
,('020234587', 'Adult Expansion',   '2019-06-01', '2019-06-30', 36)
,('020234587', 'Adult Expansion',   '2019-08-01', '2019-08-31', 36)
,('020234587', 'Adult Expansion',   '2019-09-01', '2019-09-30', 36)
,('020234587', 'Adult Expansion',   '2019-10-01', '2019-10-31', 36)
,('020234587', 'Adult Expansion',   '2019-11-01', '2019-11-30', 36)
,('020234587', 'Non-1115-Waiver',   '2019-12-01', '2019-12-31', 36)
,('020234587', 'Non-1115-Waiver',   '2020-01-01', '2020-01-31', 36)
,('020234587', 'Non-1115-Waiver',   '2020-02-01', '2020-02-29', 36)
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

| CLIENTID | AGE | ELIGBEGIN | ELIGEND | Sequence_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 52 | 2019-12-19 | 2019-12-31 | 1 |
| 123456789 | 52 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 | 2 |
| 123456789 | 52 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | 3 |
| 012345678 | 52 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-28-20 | 1 |
| 012345678 | 52 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-03-31 | 2 |
| 020234587 | 36 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-30 | 1 |
| 020234587 | 36 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-11-30 | 2 |

Then here is the current code I am using to attempt and solve this problem.

```
SELECT * INTO #y1 FROM #t
WHERE YEAR(ELIGBEGIN) = '2019'

SELECT s1.CLIENTID
       , s1.AGE
       , CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)    AS ELIGBEGIN
       , MIN(CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)) AS ELIGEND
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s1.CLIENTID ORDER BY CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)) AS Sequence_ID
INTO #CY19
FROM --[dbo].[Eligs] 
 --#t s1
 #y1 s1
INNER JOIN #y1--#t
t1 ON t1.CLIENTID = s1.CLIENTID
                   AND CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME) <= CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)
                   AND t1.DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION = 'Adult Expansion'
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM #y1 t2--#t t2
                 WHERE t2.CLIENTID = t1.CLIENTID
                   AND (CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME) + 1) >= CAST(t2.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)
                         AND CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME) < CAST(t2.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)
                   )
WHERE --s1.DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION = 'Adult Expansion' AND 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM #y1 s2--#t s2
                 WHERE s2.CLIENTID = s1.CLIENTID
                   AND CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)       > CAST(s2.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)
                   AND (CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME) - 1) <= CAST(s2.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)
                   )
        --AND s1.DEMONSTRATION_POPLUATION = 'Adult Expansion'
        --AND s1.UMIC = '1'
GROUP BY s1.CLIENTID, CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME), s1.AGE, s1.ELIGBEGIN, s1.DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION
ORDER BY s1.CLIENTID, CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)

--do the same for the 2020 calendar year:
SELECT * INTO #y2
FROM #t
WHERE YEAR(ELIGBEGIN) = '2020'

SELECT s1.CLIENTID
       , s1.AGE
       , CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)    AS ELIGBEGIN
       , MIN(CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)) AS ELIGEND
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s1.CLIENTID ORDER BY CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)) AS Sequence_ID
INTO #CY20
FROM --[dbo].[Eligs] 
 --#t s1
 #y2 s1
INNER JOIN #y2--#t
t1 ON t1.CLIENTID = s1.CLIENTID
                   AND CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME) <= CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)
                   AND s1.DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION = 'Adult Expansion'
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM #y2 t2--#t t2
                 WHERE t2.CLIENTID = t1.CLIENTID
                   AND (CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME) + 1) >= CAST(t2.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)
                         AND CAST(t1.ELIGEND AS DATETIME) < CAST(t2.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)
                   )
WHERE --s1.DEMONSTRATION_POPLUATION = 'Adult Expansion' 
    --AND 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM #y2 s2--#t s2
                 WHERE s2.CLIENTID = s1.CLIENTID
                   AND CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)       > CAST(s2.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)
                   AND (CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME) - 1) <= CAST(s2.ELIGEND AS DATETIME)
                   )
        --AND s1.DEMONSTRATION_POPLUATION = 'Adult Expansion'
        --AND s1.UMIC = '1'
GROUP BY s1.CLIENTID, CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME), s1.AGE
--ORDER BY s1.CLIENTID, CAST(s1.ELIGBEGIN AS DATETIME)
;

SELECT CLIENTID
, AGE
, ELIGBEGIN
, ELIGEND
, Sequence_ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN)
INTO #testcase
FROM (
SELECT * FROM #CY19
UNION
SELECT * FROM #CY20) a

SELECT * FROM #testcase
ORDER BY CLIENTID
```

However, the actual output of the final `SELECT * FROM #testcase` is the following:

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

| CLIENTID | AGE | ELIGBEGIN | ELIGEND | Sequence_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 52 | 2019-12-19 | 2019-12-31 | 1 |
| 123456789 | 52 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 | 2 |
| 123456789 | 52 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-12-31 | 3 |
| 020234587 | 36 | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-30 | 1 |
| 020234587 | 36 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-11-30 | 2 |

As you can see there are three major issues I'm facing with the actual output not matching the desired output.

1. I have to run the same query twice for two different years because I couldn't figure out how to otherwise segment enrollment for a member with continuous enrollment from 2019-12-31 to 2020-01-31 and beyond. If I run the code table  `#t` instead of table  `#y1`, the first CLIENTID's output would be 12/16/19 through 1/15/20, which I do not want.
2. I entirely lose one CLIENTID because they were in the 'Adult Expansion' sub-population, then in the 'Demonstration Population #3', and back into the 'Adult Expansion'
3. For some reason, the code will properly ignore preceding rows where a client's `DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION != 'Adult Expansion'` but if a CLIENTID changes from 'Adult Expansion' to a different sub-population, then the actual output still includes the enrollment dates from this different sub-population *which is directly against my desired output*. I only want the enrollment segments when an individual is enrolled in 'Adult Expansion'.

If anyone can assist in solving for the three above problems, I would be super grateful!

Thanks, in advance, for any tips!

Comment: @DaleK, all set, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a gaps-and-islands approach:

```sql
;WITH prevNextCTE
AS
(
    SELECT CLIENTID,
           DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION,
           ELIGBEGIN,
           ELIGEND,
           AGE,
           -- compare the year of the previous record to the current to create split at year end
           CASE WHEN YEAR(LAG(ELIGEND,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN)) = YEAR(ELIGBEGIN)
                THEN LAG(ELIGEND,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN)
           END AS prevELIGEND,
           -- compare the year of the next record to the current to create split at year end
           CASE WHEN YEAR(LEAD(ELIGBEGIN,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN)) = YEAR(ELIGEND)
                THEN LEAD(ELIGBEGIN,1) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN)
           END AS nextELIGBEGIN
    FROM #t
    WHERE DEMONSTRATION_POPULATION = 'Adult Expansion'
)
,islandStartCTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN) AS sequence_no
    FROM prevNextCTE
    WHERE prevELIGEND IS NULL
    OR DATEADD(DAY,1,prevELIGEND) < ELIGBEGIN
)
,islandEndCTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTID ORDER BY ELIGBEGIN) AS sequence_no
    FROM prevNextCTE
    WHERE nextELIGBEGIN IS NULL
    OR DATEADD(DAY,1,ELIGEND) < nextELIGBEGIN
)
SELECT iss.CLIENTID,
       iss.AGE,
       iss.ELIGBEGIN,
       ise.ELIGEND,
       iss.sequence_no
FROM islandStartCTE AS iss
-- left join here is not necessary but makes it easier to spot errors 
-- when a start position has no matching end (which should not occur)
LEFT
JOIN islandEndCTE AS ise 
ON ise.CLIENTID = iss.CLIENTID
AND ise.sequence_no = iss.sequence_no
```

Comment: Hey Ed! Thanks for the code, this looks like it is working for me. I'm going to just do some spot checks of it against my entire population before confirming.

So far it works with a larger test sample than I included with this post though, so it's looking good. Thanks a ton!